# LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE and drawing to the cache

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration

A view can have a layerType of LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE (view.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)) which tells it to draw a cache into the GPU. How can I tell how often this cache is drawn? What are the rules for it? I would assume every time the view calls invalidate or onDraw that the LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE must create a new cache. If this is true, for a view which calls onDraw a lot it would seem better to not have a LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE as there's twice the work (as drawing to a cache which doesn't get used would be overhead).

Anyway, I see no hooks that I can log and setting the dev options to flash the screen on GPU doesn't see to do anything either.

TL:DR, How I do I know when a new layer cache is created?

Answer (score 6):

> How I do I know when a new layer cache is created?

It gets created when you first call view.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)

Behind the scenes, a snapshot of your view is taken and uploaded as a texture to the GPU.

> How can I tell how often this cache is drawn? What are the rules for
>   it?

If you are changing certain properties like alpha, coordinates of the view, scaling or rotating the view then no new texture is uploaded to the GPU. Thats why hardware layers are good for certain types of animations because instead of redrawing (and hence reuploading the texture in case of layers) you can basically just sending transformation matrixes to the GPU.

If you change any other property of the view, a new texture is uploaded to the GPU which can be expensive if you are doing this in an animation.

> I would assume every time the view calls invalidate or onDraw that the
>   LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE must create a new cache.

Depends. Like mentioned in the previous paragraph, invalidting won't cause redraws if you are using layer friendly properties like alpha, x,y, scale and rotate. In this case no new texture is uploaded.

However invalidating because of changes to other properties will cause texture uploads and will be slower than just drawing with no layers.

Comment: Where can I get a list of these properties, which dont result in redraws ?